# jQuery Datatables.net - refresh table - getting null sAjaxSource

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the following function which should update a datatable in my ASP.NET site master page:

```
    function refreshTable(oTable) {
        var table = $(oTable).dataTable();
        var oSettings = table.fnSettings();

        //Retrieve the new data with $.getJSON. You could use it ajax too
        $.getJSON(oSettings.sAjaxSource, null, function (json) {
            table.fnClearTable(this);

            for (var i = 0; i < json.aaData.length; i++) {
                table.oApi._fnAddData(oSettings, json.aaData[i]);
            }

            oSettings.aiDisplay = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.slice();
            table.fnDraw();
        });
    }
```

This function is then called to refresh a table if an attachment is added to the site - this is the datatable settings that it should refresh.

```
var DeleteClicked = false;
var oTable;

$(document).ready(function () {
 oTable = $('#infoTable').dataTable({
        "aaSorting": [[6, "desc"]],
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": '/Web/Handlers/infoTableHandler.ashx',
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "ID", "bVisible": false },
            { "mData": "Type" },
            { "mData": "Received" },
            {
                "mData": "Action", "sWidth": "100px", "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                    var id = row.ID;
                    return "<input type=button id=" + id + " onclick='DeleteFile(" + id + ")' class=buttonBlue value=Delete />";
                },
            },
            { "mData": "IsImage", "bVisible": false }
        ],
        "bDeferRender": true,
    });
```

However - if I open Developer Tools in Chrome I get an error message saying sAjaxSource is null so i cannot then get the value from it - so oSettings is null and then I cannot get access to the sAjaxSource - anyone see anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're basically reinitializing your dataTable in the first row of `refreshTable`. Try instead:

```
function refreshTable() {
        var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
        ...
}
```

and refer directly to the global `oTable` instead of your local `table` variable